# SKAction: How to Animate Random Repeated Actions

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'd like to run a repeating `SKAction` but with random values on each repeat.  I have read [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652944/randomizing-skactions) that shows one way to do this.  However, I want my sprite's movements to be animated, not simply changing its position.  One solution I have come up with is to run a sequence of actions, with the final action calling my move method in a recursive fashion:

```
- (void)moveTheBomber {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    float randomX = //  determine new "randomX" position

    SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveToX:randomX duration:0.25f];
    SKAction *waitAction = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.15 withRange:0.4];
    SKAction *completionAction = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:0 actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime) {
        [weakSelf moveTheBomber];
    }];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveAction, waitAction, completionAction]];

    [self.bomber runAction:sequence];
}
```

Recursively calling this method feels 'icky' to me, but given my limited experience with SpriteKit, seemed like the most obvious way to accomplish this.

**How can I animate the random movement of a sprite on screen forever?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No bells or whistles, but I think this should get you on your way:

Edit: Sorry it should be:

```
SKAction *randomXMovement = [SKAction runBlock:^(void){
    NSInteger xMovement = arc4random() % 20;
    NSInteger leftOrRight = arc4random() % 2;
    if (leftOrRight == 1) {
        xMovement *= -1;
    }
    SKAction *moveX = [SKAction moveByX:xMovement y:0 duration:1.0];
    [aSprite runAction:moveX];
}];

SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[randomXMovement, wait]];
SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
[aSprite runAction: repeat];
```

Comment: Adding a corresponding wait that is equal to the duration of the `runBlock:` seems a little goofy to me, but at least it takes the recursion out.

Comment: Perhaps, but the main idea is to have an action that works as a separate entity and those block-actions are basically there to fulfill any non-basic requirements. Putting another action inside it is just one of the infinite possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Yep there's a great Action you can use.

So instead of doing your current `runAction` do this:

```
[self.bomber runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence]];
```

You'll also need to change your `moveAction` `moveToX:` value to something like `arc4random`

Comment: I'm a tad concerned about how you'll approach the random value since after you set repeatActionForever you are running that sequence not outside var (the random value). If you have it all set then never mind but if you want a little help with that let me know in a comment.

Comment: You can't use a `repeatActionForever`, because the moveAction needs to be different in each iteration.

Comment: @WayneHartman, you can use repeatActionForever, you need to do the iteration in an actionBlock.

Comment: @nickfalk does exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

As random function is only computed once, it doesn't work to put it into a sequence or a repeatForever SKAction. Ref to: [Why doesn't the call to the random function work in the sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641747/why-doesnt-the-call-to-the-random-function-work-in-the-sequence)

So a good **Swift** answer :

```
func newLocation(_ circle: SKShapeNode) {
    circle.run(SKAction.move(to: randomPosition(), duration: 2), completion: {
        [weak self] in self?.newLocation(circle)
    })
}
```

With `randomPosition()`:

```
func randomPosition() -> CGPoint {
    let height = Int(self.view?.frame.height ?? 0)
    let width = Int(self.view?.frame.width ?? 0)

    let randomPosition = CGPoint(x: Int.random(in: 0..<width), y: Int.random(in: 0..<height))

    return randomPosition
}
```

The completion of the run action is calling itself again and again, with a new computed random position.