# How to get different random delays in a SpriteKit sequence?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a sequence where i spawn a obstacle and then wait for a random amount of time, but if I run the game and for example the first random delay 1.4 seconds, but its not just for the first delay it's just all the time 1.4 and it doesn't change (it doesn't have to be 1.4 it's just an example). I have tried to make a function which has a random return value but its doesn't work. I have no idea how i could solve this. Here's my Code for the function with the random return value. If it helps obstSwitch() is the function that creates the Obstacle:

```
    func getRandomDelay() ->Double {
    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(20) + 5
    let randomDelay: Double = Double(randomNumber) / 10
    print(randomDelay)
    return randomDelay
}
```

and heres the function that get's called when the game started:

```
func gameStarted() {
    gameAbleToStart = false
    moveLine()
    scoreTimer()
    let runObstSwitch = SKAction.run {
        self.obstSwitch()
    }
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: getRandomDelay())
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([runObstSwitch, wait])
    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence))
}
```

Comment: `let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(20) + 5`should be *inside* the `getRandomDelay()` function, otherwise it is initialized only once.

Comment: Oh yes, thats right, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: What's the issue? I'm running your function in a Playground now and it seems to print unique values each time. Are you saying that this function doesn't work?

Comment: The randomDelay only get's printed out once which means it only gets called once, but i want it to be called every time the sequence restarts.

Comment: The `wait` action is created only once. You may want to use `SKAction.wait(forDuration: withinRange:)` instead.

Comment: How do I use withinRange: ? i get an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948731/skaction-how-to-generate-a-random-delay-in-generation-of-nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: getRandomDelay())
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([runObstSwitch, wait])
```

creates the `wait` action once, which is then used in the sequence,
so the same amount of idle time is spent between the `runObstSwitch`
actions.

If you want the idle time to be variable, use
[`wait(forDuration:withRange:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417760-wait) instead. For example with

```
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.5, withRange: 2.0)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([runObstSwitch, wait])
```

the delay will be a random number between 1.5-2.0/2 = 0.5 and 1.5+2.0/2 = 2.5 seconds, varying for each execution.